# ¿De qué forma podré realizar la modificación de mis datos al pulsar el botón de btn_modificar en C#?

Tags: c#, webforms

De qué forma podré realizar un boton_modificar, ya teniendo ese botón en la interfaz, de modo que usando el mismo formulario, modifique esos datos a excepción del id que no debe modificarse, solo nombre, tipo, sexo, etc., y que me actualice página para ver los resultados en la tabla.
no se si de esa forma estara bien el btn modificar, edite mi codigo, pero al momento de modificar, no me modifica los resultados en el formulario.

```
    namespace ejercicio
{
    public partial class formulario : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //   List<Mascota> mas = new List<Mascota>();
        
        private List<Mascota> mas
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["mas"] == null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["mas"] = new List<Mascota>();
                }
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["mas"] as List<Mascota>;
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["mas"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.tablaVista1.DataSource = mas;
                this.tablaVista1.DataBind();
            }
        }


        protected void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int id = int.Parse(txtIdentificador.Text);
            var cantidadRepeticiones = mas.Count(m => m.Id == id);

            if (cantidadRepeticiones == 0)
            {
                Mascota m = new Mascota();

                m.Id = id;
                m.Nombre = txtNombreMascota.Text;
                m.Tipo = ddlTipoMascota.Text;
                m.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
                m.FechaUltimaVisita = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFecha.Text);
                m.NombreDuenio = txtNombreDuenio.Text;
                m.EmailContacto = txtEmail.Text;
                mas.Add(m);
                
            }
        }

        protected void btnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            int id = int.Parse(txtIdentificador.Text);
            var mascota = from m in mas where m.Id == id select m;
            if (mascota !=null)
            {
                Mascota m = new Mascota();
                m.Nombre = txtNombreDuenio.Text;
                m.Tipo = ddlTipoMascota.Text;
                m.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
                m.FechaUltimaVisita = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFecha.Text);
                m.NombreDuenio = txtNombreDuenio.Text;
                m.EmailContacto = txtEmail.Text;
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tu trabajas con base de datos?

Comment: nop, pa ese mi problemita, no tengo q usar base de datos, con base mas facil, si no me equivoco, en este caso tengo q usarla sin base de datos

Comment: Te será útil crear un constructor para la clase. Además, dentro de la clase puedes tener una variable estática que guarde el último id de modo que se generen solos. Sumado a esto, práctica la encapsulación: variables privadas y getters y setters públicos limitando lo que se puede modificar fuera de la clase. Al ID claramente no le haces un setter así no se puede cambiar.

Comment: en ese caso como seria;

Comment: Es que para modificar la cosa cambia, tienes q saber q registro vas a modificar, por lo que debes hacer una busqueda basada en algun criterio y modificar el dato q deseas. Dime q es lo q tienes pensado hacer?

Comment: por ahora cree un vinculo en la tabla para redireccionarme a otro formulario, modificar, la cual me trae el mismo formulario, pero ahora quiero al pinchar la fila de algun modificar pueda modificar esos datos a excepcion del id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno voy a tratar de explicarte con un ejemplo, a ver si esto te ayuda.

Cuando tu modificas un dato, debes tener un campo que identifique a la entidad que vas a modificar, que en este caso sería el id, lo que debes hacer es obtener de alguna forma el id de la entidad a modificar, buscar en esa lista, tabla o estructura de datos la entidad que coincida con ese id (que debe ser un id único que identifique cada entidad), y una vez obtenida la entidad hacer los cambios necesarios y ya está:

```
protected void btnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = ...; //Obtienes el id de alguna forma(imagino sepas)
    var mascota = from m in mascotas
                  where m.id == id
                  select m;
    
    if(mascota != null)
    {
       //Haces los cambios que desees a las propiedades que desees
       mascota.Nombre = ...;
    }
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es una consulta **Linq** la cual va a obtener la mascota que coincida con el id buscado y si se encontró una mascota pues se hacen los cambios deseados.

Comment: Vale pa gracias, intentaré aplicarlo

Comment: edite el codigo, para ver si seria asi, o no

Comment: @CristianGuerreroNenen, pruebalo y dime

Comment: nada, realizo el click, pero no me carga la tabla para ver si se modificaron los datos, le indico id 12 por ejemplo, donde ya registre datos, despues indico el id 12, mas el nombre lo modifico, etc, hago click en modificar pero no modifica la fila

Comment: igual me complique con el modificar,

Comment: @CristianGuerreroNenen resolviste ya?

Comment: No nada pa. O pude